# How to connect a client to multiple server sockets?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `spring-integration` to connect a client to a server `socket` using the following components:

```
DirectChannel
TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean
TcpOutboundGateway
@MessagingGateway
```

Problem: the `TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean` is tied to a specific socket port. I'd like to connect the client to multiple server sockets.

How could I achieve this? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TCP connection is bound to following parameters:

- Source address
- Source port
- Remote address
- Remote port

I think it's not intended to offer the possibilty to create one to many connections via one socket since this would be against the TCP definition.

[Wiki-Article for TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

So the solution would be to create multiple sockets, each holding one connection to a different server.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. You need a separate connection factory for each server/port.

There's not currently any mechanism in Spring Integration to dynamically select a TCP host/port for each message.

Such a mechanism would probably need to cache connections to avoid having to open a new socket for each request. Feel free to open a new feature JIRA issue and we'll consider it for a future release.